# Unable to implement AdColony for Unity/Android // AdColony requires AndroidApiLevel14 in PlayerSettings

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, adcolony

every time i'm trying to implement AdColony SDK in Unity i keep getting this same error message. I don't understand why?! I've set the Android SDK path and JDK path both is system variables and within unity settings but this keep showing everytime i try to run the project.

```
AdColony requires AndroidApiLevel14 in PlayerSettings
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
AdColony.Editor.ADCManifestProcessor:CheckMinSDKVersion() (at Assets/AdColony/Editor/ADCManifestProcessor.cs:20)
AdColony.Editor.ADCManifestProcessor:Process() (at Assets/AdColony/Editor/ADCManifestProcessor.cs:25)
AdColony.Editor.ADCManifestProcessor:.cctor() (at Assets/AdColony/Editor/ADCManifestProcessor.cs:15)
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes()
```

also platform implementation not set

i've tried to configure it as it says in the AdColony documentation as such

```
    AdColony.Ads.Configure (appID, null, zoneID);
```

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AdColony requires AndroidApiLevel14 in PlayerSettings

You need to set minimum Android API Level 14 in Player Setting.

File -> Build Settings -> Select Android Platform -> Player Settings Button -> Select Other Settings from side Panel -> Identification -> Minimum API Level -> Select 14 or greater.